# How do I delete a single file from a tar.gz archive

Tags: tar, gzip

I have a huge tarbell archive with an excessively large or corrupt error_log that causes the archive to hang when attempting to extract it. Is there a way to remove this from the archive before unzipping or extract the archive without extracting that specific file on Mac OS X terminal?

I found this post on how to [efficiently-remove-files-from-large-tgz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80239/efficiently-remove-files-from-large-tgz) however, I tried the --delete flag, but received this error:

```
tar: Option --delete is not supported
```

Is there a way to:

1. remove the file from the archive without unzipping it?
2. extract the archive but exclude the file?

Comment: Which version of `tar` are you using? If its outdated then try to update to the latest version and check the `man` page if `tar` supports `--delete` as an option.

Comment: The `--delete` option is specific to some `tar` programs (notably the default available under linux).   From memory, the default tar under macos does not support that.   You'll need to read the man/help file, or obtain a program that supports such functionality.   All else failing, unzip the `.tar.gz` file, extract everything from the archive, delete the unwanted file, and then rebuild the archive.

Comment: Santosh and Peter, thank you so much for your responses. Santosh, not sure which version of tar is running on Mac OS x nor how to update it. Peter, thanks too. This isn't an option, since extracting the archive fails due to how large the error_log is.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments it's not possible to remove the file using tar, but you can exclude the file when extracting:

```
tar -zxvf file.tar.gz --exclude "file_to_exclude"
```

Answer (score 19):

You can repackage it like this:

```
tar -czvf ./new.tar.gz --exclude='._*' @old.tar.gz
```

I used `._*` to remove all [`._files`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleSingle_and_AppleDouble_formats), but you can use any pattern you like, including a full path, directory, filename, or whatever.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually solves my issue of not adding additional files into the tar in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: Requires [bsdtar](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/libarchive-tools/bsdtar.1.en.html) though, GNU tar does not support '@' syntax.

Answer (score 8):

I did that in tree steps. Hopefully will help others in the future.

```
gzip -d file.tar.gz
tar -f file.tar --delete folder1/file1.txt --delete folder2/file2.txt
gzip -9 file.tar
```

If you have multiple files use this. But the archives them must have all the files you want to delete, or tar will give a error.

```
for f in *.tar.gz
do
        echo "Processing file $f"
        gzip -d "$f"
        tar -f "${f%.*}" --delete folder1/file1.txt --delete folder2/file2.txt
        gzip -9 "${f%.*}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to remove the jdk directory from the elasticsearch-oss archive with a one liner, and this is what I came up with:

```
gzip -d elasticsearch-oss-7.10.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz -c | tar --delete --wildcards */jdk | gzip - > /tmp/tmp.$$.tar.gz && mv /tmp/tmp.$$.tar.gz elasticsearch-oss-7.10.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

I further refined this to include the download:

```
curl -Ss https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss-7.10.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz | gzip -d - -c | tar --delete --wildcards */jdk | gzip - > elasticsearch-oss-7.10.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

Works a treat on ubuntu 20.04, so gnu tar which does not support the @ sign.

Answer (score -9):

Dear you can delete the archive file through the same format as we remove the directory from below command through

command:- rm -rf archive file name
r:- recursively

Comment: I admire that you keep this post when it's so obvious you didn't understand the question so your reply is really very weird. By the way, I didn't downvote it as it has already enough down votes.