# How to Modify tar.gz file in windows?

Tags: tar

I have a `tr.gz` backup file, and I need to delete some file inside of this `tar.gz` file without extract the `tar.gz` file.

Is there any solution (command line or software) in windows?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962501/how-do-i-delete-a-single-file-from-a-tar-gz-archive) might help. Same issue described in that question.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to remove the file from tar, but you can exclude a file by the following command

```
tar -zxvf file.tar.gz --exclude "file_to_exclude"
```

or 
take a backup too and proceed

OR

```
tar -cvf files.tar --remove-files my_directory
```